# How to Change Toolbar Elevation Color?

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-elevation

In app there are is an option to change the theme color and depending on theme color I am changing the color of toolbar background using following line:

```
toolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
```

However, I could not find anything which can help me to change the color of Elevation. Here is the toolbar xml:

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="4dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/headset"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="@string/contact_us"
                android:textColor="@color/gray"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

Please let me know how can I do it programmatically.

Comment: What is parent of toolbar? post xml

Comment: @GaneshPokale posted xml.

Comment: @FaisalShaikh starting with android API 28, now you can change the shadow color 
`android:outlineAmbientShadowColor`
        `android:outlineSpotShadowColor`

Answer (score 0):

set AppBarLayout Elevation

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    app:elevation="0dp">
```

AppTheme

```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
      <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/green_tataki</item>
    </style>
```